# Select from three tables - mysql and php

Tags: mysql, select

I've got the three tables below from which I wish to get the following selects: 
1.) Select all items from `collaboration` and group them by `group_id` in `group_members` for a given user
This means that when the user logs in, (s)he will see all (and only) `collaboration` items belonging to the groups where he is group member.
2.) For each `group_id`, select all collaboration items.
This means that when a user selects any group (`group_id`) from 1 above, he's going to see all the `collaboration`items belonging to the selected group (`group_id`)

Constraints: Each user MUST be a group member. The `users`table is there to supply `firstname`and `lastname` of user.

This is what I tried for 1 to no avail!

```
    function OrderByGroup_id($username) {
      $data = array();
      $currenttime = time();
      $q = "
      SELECT *
      FROM collaboration
      INNER JOIN group_members ON collaboration.group_id = group_members.group_id
      INNER JOIN users ON users.username = group_members.username
      WHERE collaboration.parent_id IS NULL and collaboration.is_comment = 0 
      AND group_members.username = :user group by collaboration.group_id";
      $sq = $this->connection->prepare($q);
      $sq->execute(array(':user' => $username));
    while($row = $sq->fetch()) {
      $json = array();
      $json['title'] = $row['title'];
      $json['question'] = $row['content'];
      $json['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
      $json['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
      $json['timestamp'] = $row['timestamp'];
      $json['key'] = $row['group_id'];
      $data[] = $json;
     }
      $allposts =json_encode($data);
      return $allposts= json_decode($allposts, true);
    }
```

Here are the tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `collaboration` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `is_comment` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `file` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `points` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `firstname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group_members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Your "what I've tried" section is blank.

Comment: I thought the "what I've tried" section was lost in markdown, but no, there is nothing at all (was, before the update).

Comment: Sorry! I've updated to show one of selects that I tried. Cheers!

Comment: "`WHERE ... collaboration.is_comment IS NULL`" -- Man, I really hate three-state booleans

Comment: `WHERE ... collaboration.is_comment IS NULL` will never match anything, as `is_comment` is set `NOT NULL` and there are no `OUTER JOIN`s (`LEFT` or `RIGHT`). Did you mean `IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak You're right! `collaboration.is_comment IS NULL` will not  match anything! I meant `IS NULL` actually. I thought the `INNER JOIN`s will do.

Comment: @dorogz an `[INNER] JOIN` joins only the rows that have a matching row in the other table. A `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` adds `null` rows as neccessary to the right table and vice versa for `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN`: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Thanks for that information and for the link of course!

Comment: Your query does exactly what you have asked for. How does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following select does deliver  the request for question 1. However, I know the query is not optimal because I do select entries that I don't need at the moment. For example the use of * 
I would like to select only `title`, `content`, `timestamp`, `group_id`, from *collaboration* and `firstname`, `lastname`, from *users*

```
    
    SELECT * FROM collaboration
    INNER JOIN group_members ON collaboration.group_id = group_members.group_id
    INNER JOIN users ON users.username = collaboration.author
    WHERE collaboration.parent_id IS NULL and collaboration.is_comment = 0 
    AND group_members.username = :user 
    GROUP BY collaboration.group_id
    ORDER BY collaboration.timestamp DESC
```